# Calculate Volume of Thickness/Difference Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator

I have two LiDAR datasets, and I would like to know the volume of their difference. I used raster calculator to produce a "difference" raster. What I need now is a way to be able to calculate the total volume of that raster. I don't think Surface Volume, nor Cut Fill, is what I am after as they both use a reference plane or require before/after rasters.

Is there a tool that is well suited to this type of calculation?

Comment: If you have a "difference" raster, computing the volume from zero level makes sense to me.

Comment: Average raster value times cell size squared.

Comment: One lidar is before, 2nd - -after, so both tools will do.